# Servidor rechaza solicitudes

Tags: python, socket

Hola estoy creando un programa para controlar el mouse remotamente con sockets y pyautogui.
Uso el cliente en bucle para mandar constantemente la ubicacion de mi raton.pero a la tercera repeticion el servidor rechaza la conexion.
No se porque me passa esto.
Y me gustaria que alguien mas experimentado en sockets me ayudara.
O me ensenyara una forma de enviar muchos datos desde el cliente al servidor sin que me rechaze la conexion

Cliente

```
import socket
import pyautogui
import time

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket()

sock.connect((host, port))

while True:
  pos = pyautogui.position()

  px=pos[0]
  
  py=pos[1]

  px=str(px)

  py=str(py)

  soc=px+","+py

  soc=str(soc)

  print(soc)

  sock.send(soc.encode("utf-8"))
  time.sleep(1)
```

servidor

```
import socket
import pyautogui

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ("Socket Created")
sock.bind((host, port))
print ("socket bind complete")
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept() 
    try:
        print('Conexión con {}.'.format(addr))
        while True:
            datos = conn.recv(4096)

            daa=datos.decode("utf-8")
            x, y = daa.split(',')
            x = int(x)
            y = int(y)
            pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
            pyautogui.moveTo(x,y)
            
         
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Codigo de error

```
1307,1029
390,588
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\cuent\OneDrive\Documentos\control remoto\cli.py", line 29, in <module>
    sock.send(soc.encode("utf-8"))
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host
PS C:\Users\cuent\OneDrive\Documentos\control remoto>
```

Comment: En el cliente envías datos con sock.send(), pero en el servidor no los recibe, no veo un c.recv() o algo parecido, debería ir tras el s.accept() supongo. Ese es el primer error. Van a haber más, te recomiendo buscar un ejemplo básico de sockets y adaptarlo a tu caso.

Comment: Ya esta pero sigue igual

Comment: Aparte de lo que te comentan, otro error está en el `while` que tienes, ahí hay un `break`, con eso detienes el bucle y se acaba todo. Lo que debe ir en el segundo `while` sería el `recv` y no todo el proceso de aceptar la conexión (a menos que tengas múltiples clientes)

Comment: sigue igual aunque quite el break

Comment: Actualiza el código de la pregunta, decir que sigue igual no nos indica nada

Comment: lo acabo de editar,hecho

Comment: He hecho un copy y paste con el código y en mi caso funciona no he cambiado nada . ¿Puede ser que tengas el puerto en el firewall bloqueado o algun programa que pueda denegar la conexion? Puese un print haver si s'enviaba al servidor y esto lo que saque de una linea.

Cliente : 1400,1109
Servidor: b'1400,1109'

Comment: Pues seguramente sea algo como eso.Lo que sacastes con el print es la posición de tu mouse